# How to evaluate time of each function in a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

My UIViewController is loaded fairly slowly. There are several init functions in viewdidload. I am trying to figure out which function consumes such much time. Do you know how to evaluate time of each function in a specific class. I use iOS 7, XCODE 5.

More specific, my UIViewController contains a UITableView. At the beginning, I think loading data for UITableView takes such time. However, the loading time of this UITableView is not so much. I put a waiting dialog at the first point of ViewDidLoad, and then when a UITableView ends loading, I remove this dialog. This dialog since its appearance, ends very quickly. The problem is why the UIViewController appears so slowly.

Comment: I would strongly recommend profiling the app in Instruments, built in to Xcode. You can use the Time Profiler template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `NSDate` object before calling the method like `NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];` and get the time interval after the method call to which you want to get the time interval. `NSTimeInterval interval = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];`